# C# Dynamic SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlCommand s2 = new SqlCommand();
s2.CommandText = @"declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select sys_RespNum from ' + quotename(@tableName) + 'where' + 'respid' + 'in' + '(' + @emails + ')';
exec (@sql);
```

What's wrong with the code? I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near @emails

Comment: Note that you should not build SQL commands with string concatenation, it is extremely dangerous because it's so easy to hack. Instead you should use the overload of the Query method you're using to supply the parameters separately.

Comment: Print your SQL string, you missed several spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed space

```
set @sql = 'select sys_RespNum from ' + quotename(@tableName) + ' where ' + ' respid ' + ' in ' + '( ' + @emails + ' )';
exec (@sql);
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'jpack@cherrytreeinn.com'.

Still error

Comment: @LukeMarkLorenzoBadeo check now there will be another space after parenthesis

Comment: That could just be `... + ' where respid in (' + ...` instead.  That way it's easier to see the need for the spaces.